# Is Validation not applicable for put request in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and was developing a simple crud application. I have created a student model with few validations to few fields to test if validation is working or not. While creating a new student using a `post` request to `/students`, the validation is working. Now I want the same validations to be applicable while updating the student as well since the fields need to be consistent for either creating/updating. I have configured a `put` request to `/students/{id}`to update the student basing on the id. But the validations are not working and if I change the `put` to `post`, instead of getting json response as `{message:"name should have atleast 4 characters"}`, I am getting an exception.. as

`{ "timestamp": "2021-06-29T10:06:52.866+00:00", "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error", "trace": "org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.demo.service.Studentservice.updateStudent(Studentservice.java:42)\r\n\tat com.demo.controller.StudentController.updateStudent(StudentController.java:47)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)\r\n\t... 66 more\r\nCaused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.demo.model.Student] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='name should have min of 4 characters', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.demo.model.Student, messageTemplate='name should have min of 4 characters'}\n]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:214)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:100)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\r\n\t... 67 more\r\n", "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction", "path": "/students/3" }`in my postman...

Here is the structure of the code:

`Student.java`

```
package com.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Size(min=4,message = "name should have min of 4 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message="name should not be null")
    private String name;
    private int age;
    @Email
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

`StudentRepository.java`

```
package com.demo.repository;

import com.demo.model.Student;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Integer> {
}
```

`Studentservice.java`

```
package com.demo.service;
import com.demo.errors.StudentNotFoundException;
import com.demo.model.Student;
import com.demo.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.*;

@Service
public class Studentservice {
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    //getting all students
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        studentRepository.findAll().forEach(students::add);
        return students;
    }

   //find student
   public Student getStudent(int id){
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException(id));
   }

   //create a student
    public Student createStudent(Student student){
       return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    //delete a student
    public void deleteStudent(int id){
        getStudent(id);
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    //update student
    public void updateStudent(int id,Student student ){
        if(getStudent(id)!=null){
            studentRepository.save(student);
        }
    }
}
```

`StudentController.java`

```
package com.demo.controller;

import com.demo.model.Student;
import com.demo.service.Studentservice;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.*;

@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    Studentservice studentservice;

    //get students
    @GetMapping("/students")
    private List<Student> fetchStudents(){
        return studentservice.getStudents();
    }

    //get student
    @GetMapping("/students/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Object> fetchStudent(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        Student found= studentservice.getStudent(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(found,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //create student
    @PostMapping("/students")
    private ResponseEntity<Object> createStudent(@Valid @RequestBody Student student) {
        Student s = studentservice.createStudent(student);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(s, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    //delete student
    @DeleteMapping("/students/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Object> deleteStudent(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        studentservice.deleteStudent(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("deleted student",HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    //update student
    @PutMapping("/students/{id}")
    private ResponseEntity<Object> updateStudent(@Valid @PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestBody Student student){
        studentservice.updateStudent(id,student);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("updated succesfully",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

`StudentNotFoundException.java`

```
package com.demo.errors;

public class StudentNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public StudentNotFoundException(int id){
        super("Student not found at:"+ id);
    }

}
```

`InputValidationHandler.java`

```
package com.demo.errors;

import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
import java.util.*;

@ControllerAdvice
public class InputValidationHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        Map<String,String>errors=new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error)->{
            String fieldName=((FieldError) error).getField();
            String message=error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName,message);
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(errors,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the @Valid annotation just before the request body parameter, in your put endpoint you have put it before the id and because of that the validation is not working

Comment: Now validation is working...But if dont use name in the update body..it is showing that name cant be null.. I mean I if chose not to update name and update only age/email, then name validation is popping up..

Comment: this is because you have annotated name field as @NotEmpty and this checks that the field is not null and is not empty string. And if you want to have different behaviour for this field depending on the operation (post or put) you will have to use different objects

Comment: ok for updating i want to use different behaviour..how can i do it? i want update validation to check if the provided fields are only validated but not all of them

Comment: you should use two different objects and specify different validations in each of them depending on the ones that you want to apply in each operation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `dto` package like me, you will also get these errors. So in your `dto` request you have to add the `Java` bean validations like below. So that you will validate the `requestData` of your `dto`. You can also delete the validation for the one of the entity:

```
package com.microspring.departementservice.dto;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class DepartementRequest {
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = " department name should have at least 2 characters")
    private String departmentName;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = " department address should have at least 2 characters")
    private String departmentAddress;
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = " department code should have at least 2 characters")
    private String departmentCode;
}
```

It worked for me and also add the valid annotation in your controller.